# Can we change comparison view to top-bottom layout

Tags: notepad++

With current version 6.6.9 of notepad++, when I want to compare 2 open files, I will move one of them to another view and synchronize vertical scrollbar to compare them, the 2 views are placed in left-right style, can we change them to top-bottom style? (some lines are very long, line wrapping feature is not preferred)

Comment: Why not use the `Compare` plugin?

Comment: @BrandonB thanks for your suggestion, the plugin can show me place of delta, but when I want to confirm/check the delta (i.e. I want to know what is the change made to the file by other team members), the visible area is still too small and I must scroll the scroll-bar frequently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the separator bar between the two files and choose one of the `Rotate` Options.

[image]